# Running a command a different user using `su` gives "standard in must be a tty"

Tags: su, automated-testing

I am using [STAF](http://staf.sourceforge.net/docs.php) to automate db2 interface testing with our product. I am able to run the command using `su - db2inst1 -c "/home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2 list database directory"` but when I try the same command with the staf interface I am getting the error:

```
standard in must be a tty
```

I commented the "Defaults requiretty" in /etc/sudoers, but still have the same issue.

Comment: How were you connecting or logging in to the terminal? Using ssh ? Using docker exec ? Other ?  A pty is not being allocated. Use 'ssh -t' or 'ssh -tt' to control allocation of pty when logging in with ssh. That and two other answers on how to solve or work around missing tty here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944634/su-command-in-docker-returns-must-be-run-from-terminal/41872292#41872292

Answer (score 2):

Drop the lone dash (-) in your su command. That triggers su to ask for a login shell. A tty might be required by some program in your login chain.

Comment: If you remove the dash, you'll need to make sure to set the DB2-related environment variables for that command.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/sudoers` does not govern the behavior of `su`. You want something like

```
sudo -u db2inst1 "/home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2 list database directory"
```

Comment: Actually sudo doesnot work with STAF framework, so I need to execute it with su - useranem -c Command only.

Comment: `su` doesn't normally have the restriction of needing to run in a tty; it's used all the time in init scripts, for example. Could this be a limitation of the db2 binary or of staf? What happens when you put the command into a shell script and run it?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link:
I tried the 2nd option of **ssh -t username@server 'sudo command'**. 
It worked for me.
https://math-linux.com/linux/bash/article/error-standard-in-must-be-a-tty-when-doing-ssh-username-server-sudo-command